# Porting Plib In OpenGL-ES

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to port Plib from OpenGl to OpenGL-Es.So I need some suggestions on that.
Is it really possible or not?because I haven't found anyone doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the excellent advice [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273589/1262542), together with the  [difference specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_cm_spec_2.0.25.pdf) that compares OpenGL ES 2 to OpenGL 2.

I cannot *really* comment on the possibility of this endeavour. I'd say, you're free to hold forth about features that do not map to OpenGL ES 2 well (guarded with exceptions s.t. the client knows as soon as possible). However, if this means forfeiting core features, you're lost.